# make a loop that can select segments in polyline one by one

Tags: python

The goal is to write a python script that will allow me to move on a polyline making a selection segment by segment as shown in the pictures.  I hope to find a loop that can make that !!

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: What library/software are you using?
What is the format of your line?

Comment: i'm working with arcpy (arcgis) and it is a shapefile format

Comment: Welcom to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. Please also specify the exact release of ArcGIS in the body of the question, and include the code you have written. All questions requesting coding help should include code, as text, formatted with four leading spaces (the `{}` button does this).